# dygraph (in r)'s annotations not displayed

Tags: r, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I'm in the process of replacing a ggplot2 plot with a dygraph in one of my shiny apps since it's very visually appealing package and the interactivity is very fluid.
I require to be able to display text above certain candles in a candlechart. I have tried the simplest of annotations but I cannot get it to work in a candlestick dygraph.

```
d <- dygraph(mat) %>% 
  dyCandlestick() %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20) %>% 
  dyAnnotation(x = "2018-09-04", text = "Hi")

d
```

data example:

```
mat <- structure(c(267.84, 268.96, 271.2, 272.51, 273.31, 274.4, 273.68, 
                   274.75, 276.42, 279.35, 278.03, 279.48, 279.8, 280.17, 282.74, 
                   284.02, 284.16, 284.25, 285.93, 282.6, 282.73, 281.07, 280.08, 
                   273.45, 259.94, 268.5, 268.01, 260.8, 263.83, 263.97, 264.31, 
                   271.57, 272.32, 272.03, 271.9, 271.1, 271.79, 275.93, 278.11, 
                   275.68, 271.41, 265.8, 267.73, 273.3, 270.42, 273.55, 275.7, 
                   279.2, 279.84, 277.81, 275.88, 274.5, 273.35, 270.94, 270.9, 
                   267.91, 264.17, 262.13, 266.17, 260.75, 261.12, 262.55, 258.87, 
                   256.75, 265.55, 263.42, 261.37, 264.27, 263.47, 265.26, 267.41, 
                   267, 269.33, 270.69, 269.65, 268.81, 267.26, 267.73, 262.91, 
                   264.79, 267, 267.26, 263.87, 264.76, 262.26, 261.52, 266.89, 
                   266.5, 267.68, 270.34, 272.16, 273.34, 271.59, 271.14, 271.94, 
                   271.62, 273.01, 273.96, 271.17, 272.91, 272.15, 270.31, 270.5, 
                   272.15, 272.41, 274.53, 275.05, 275.79, 277.95, 276.85, 278.44, 
                   279.03, 279.19, 279.01, 276.6, 275.49, 274, 276.27, 275.96, 275.66, 
                   273.44, 271.64, 272.26, 269.29, 272.12, 269.51, 272.87, 272.17, 
                   273.14, 276.55, 278.41, 277.15, 278.28, 279.17, 279.64, 278.47, 
                   280.56, 280.31, 279.77, 279.45, 281.79, 281.33, 283.2, 283.71, 
                   281.51, 280.81, 281.56, 279.39, 282.53, 283.64, 285.39, 285.39, 
                   285.53, 283.45, 283.47, 282.92, 282.38, 283.4, 283.83, 285.57, 
                   286.25, 285.88, 285.97, 286.44, 288.86, 290.3, 290.16, 290.94, 
                   289.84, 289.84, 289.41, 289.15, 286.98, 288.74, 287.37, 289.06, 
                   290.32, 291.06, 290.82, 289.58, 290.97, 292.64, 293.09, 291.34, 
                   291.53, 290.91, 290.41, 289.99, 292.11, 291.56, 292.74, 291.18, 
                   289.69, 287.05, 287.39, 286.83, 277.08, 276.77, 275.55, 276.6, 
                   280.44, 268.81, 270.64, 272.16, 273.56, 274.1, 275.25, 274.42, 
                   276.12, 278.11, 280.09, 280.05, 279.96, 280.41, 282.69, 283.62, 
                   284.7, 284.27, 286.6285, 286.43, 284.736, 283.3, 283.06, 280.23, 
                   275.85, 269.7, 272.36, 268.17, 263.61, 267.01, 266.62, 270, 273.04, 
                   275.32, 273.67, 274.72, 273.05, 274.71, 278.01, 278.92, 276.19, 
                   273.17, 269.72, 272.89, 273.39, 273.18, 274.24, 278.87, 279.91, 
                   280.41, 278.02, 276.61, 275.39, 274.3957, 271.67, 273.27, 268.87, 
                   265.02, 265.43, 266.77, 262.64, 265.26, 263.13, 261.31, 264.355, 
                   266.64, 265.11, 264.84, 266.04, 265.64, 267, 267.54, 268.2, 270.87, 
                   271.3, 269.88, 269.06, 267.89, 267.9762, 264.13, 267.2452, 267.34, 
                   267.89, 265.1, 265.68, 263.36, 266.7892, 268.02, 267.325, 269.865, 
                   272.39, 273.15, 274.08, 271.61, 272.76, 273.23, 272.03, 273.98, 
                   274.25, 273.39, 273.22, 272.86, 271.17, 273.11, 272.49, 273.94, 
                   275.185, 275.53, 277.52, 278.28, 278.25, 279.37, 279.33, 279.48, 
                   279.33, 277.51, 276.7, 275.75, 276.72, 275.98, 275.785, 273.6162, 
                   272.56, 273.865, 271.75, 273.66, 272.04, 272.98, 273.18, 275.84, 
                   277.96, 279.01, 278.04, 279.43, 279.93, 279.803, 280.91, 281.18, 
                   280.74, 280.48, 280.43, 282.56, 284.37, 284.11, 283.82, 281.69, 
                   282.02, 282.13, 282.58, 283.6577, 284.99, 286.01, 285.91, 285.97, 
                   284.055, 284.16, 284.17, 282.54, 285.04, 285.5601, 285.97, 287.31, 
                   286.76, 286.94, 287.67, 289.9, 290.4175, 291.74, 291.36, 290.81, 
                   290.21, 289.64, 289.49, 288.7, 289.04, 289.55, 289.8, 291.0384, 
                   291.27, 290.86, 291.58, 291.69, 293.94, 293.22, 291.5, 291.65, 
                   292.24, 291.91, 291.28, 292.93, 292.355, 293.21, 291.24, 290.27, 
                   288.22, 288.86, 286.91, 278.9, 277.09, 277.04, 280.82, 281.15, 
                   267.4, 268.96, 270.5447, 271.95, 272.98, 274.081, 272.92, 274.56, 
                   276.0819, 276.18, 276.97, 278.58, 279.14, 280.11, 282.37, 281.84, 
                   282.405, 283.96, 284.5, 281.22, 280.68, 280.68, 275.41, 263.31, 
                   258.7, 267.58, 257.59, 252.92, 261.6644, 263.31, 264.3, 268.77, 
                   272.27, 270.5, 269.94, 269.64, 271.25, 275.26, 274.36, 271.29, 
                   266, 264.82, 267.61, 271.18, 270.2, 272.42, 275.34, 278.0801, 
                   276.03, 274.67, 274.43, 274.14, 268.62, 270.18, 270.19, 263.36, 
                   257.83, 259.41, 258.84, 258.58, 259.8389, 254.67, 256.84, 256.6, 
                   264.32, 258, 259.9356, 262.98, 263.39, 265.06, 264.01, 266.07, 
                   268.75, 269.87, 267.72, 265.61, 265.35, 261.28, 260.85, 264.29, 
                   265.5, 264.43, 262.11, 262.76, 259.05, 261.15, 266.11, 265.15, 
                   267.09, 270.22, 271.58, 272.36, 270.03, 271.11, 271.13, 270.93, 
                   271.3512, 272.24, 270.99, 270.78, 271.58, 267.76, 270.42, 270.255, 
                   272.33, 274.26, 274.18, 275.09, 276.34, 276.66, 278.31, 278.19, 
                   277.8, 278.0599, 275.35, 274.95, 273.53, 275.59, 273.68, 274.49, 
                   269.1, 270.79, 269.18, 268.49, 271.1495, 269.24, 270.42, 270.96, 
                   272.715, 276.5, 278.08, 276.52, 277.6, 278.66, 278.84, 278.41, 
                   280.06, 279.46, 279.5, 279.06, 280.63, 281.28, 283.09, 280.38, 
                   279.36, 280.38, 280.1315, 279.16, 282.33, 283.2015, 285.24, 284.94, 
                   284.915, 282.36, 281.77, 282.4833, 280.16, 283.36, 283.37, 285.06, 
                   285.7135, 285.575, 285.43, 286.38, 288.68, 289.4, 289.8854, 289.63, 
                   289.29, 288.68, 287.89, 287, 286.71, 287.88, 286.975, 288.23, 
                   289.995, 290, 289.03, 289.55, 290.825, 291.2363, 291.81, 290.37, 
                   290.4833, 289.41, 290.1, 289.95, 290.98, 291.14, 291.32, 287.66, 
                   286.22, 285.5, 286.77, 277.88, 270.36, 272.37, 274.3, 276.07, 
                   277.56, 268.77, 270.47, 271.61, 273.42, 273.92, 274.54, 274.12, 
                   276.12, 277.92, 276.97, 279.61, 279.14, 280.41, 282.69, 283.29, 
                   283.18, 283.3, 286.58, 284.68, 281.76, 281.9, 281.58, 275.45, 
                   263.93, 269.13, 267.67, 257.63, 261.5, 265.34, 266, 269.59, 273.03, 
                   273.11, 271.4, 270.05, 270.4, 274.71, 277.9, 274.43, 271.65, 
                   267.7, 269.08, 272.19, 272.88, 272.78, 274.1, 278.87, 278.52, 
                   276.72, 275.3, 275, 274.2, 270.49, 270.95, 270.43, 263.67, 258.05, 
                   265.11, 260.6, 259.83, 263.15, 257.47, 260.77, 263.56, 265.64, 
                   259.72, 261, 265.15, 263.76, 265.93, 265.15, 267.33, 270.19, 
                   270.39, 268.89, 266.61, 266.57, 262.98, 263.63, 266.31, 266.56, 
                   264.51, 264.98, 263.2, 262.62, 266.02, 266.92, 266.92, 269.5, 
                   272.02, 272.85, 272.98, 271.1, 272.24, 272.01, 271.33, 273.37, 
                   272.61, 273.36, 272.8, 272.15, 269.02, 272.61, 270.94, 273.6, 
                   274.9, 275.1, 277.4, 277.37, 278.19, 278.56, 278.92, 278.03, 
                   278.73, 277.13, 276.56, 275.5, 275.97, 274.24, 274.74, 271, 271.6, 
                   269.35, 270.89, 271.28, 271.86, 270.9, 273.11, 275.42, 277.9, 
                   278.9, 276.86, 279.37, 279.59, 279.34, 280.47, 281.06, 280, 279.68, 
                   280.2, 281.61, 284.01, 283.34, 281.42, 279.95, 281.33, 280.86, 
                   282.39, 283.6, 284.64, 285.58, 285.46, 285.07, 283.16, 282.1, 
                   283.9, 281.78, 284.06, 285.06, 285.67, 286.34, 286.17, 285.79, 
                   287.51, 289.78, 289.92, 291.48, 290.3, 290.31, 289.81, 289.03, 
                   288.16, 287.6, 288.1, 289.05, 289.12, 290.83, 290.88, 289.34, 
                   290.91, 291.22, 293.58, 291.99, 291.02, 290.75, 289.88, 290.69, 
                   290.72, 291.73, 291.56, 291.72, 289.44, 287.82, 287.82, 287.4, 
                   278.3, 272.17, 275.95, 274.4, 280.4, 280.055), .Dim = c(201L, 
                                                                           4L), .Dimnames = list(c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", 
                                                                                                   "2018-01-05", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", 
                                                                                                   "2018-01-12", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", 
                                                                                                   "2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-26", 
                                                                                                   "2018-01-29", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-01", "2018-02-02", 
                                                                                                   "2018-02-05", "2018-02-06", "2018-02-07", "2018-02-08", "2018-02-09", 
                                                                                                   "2018-02-12", "2018-02-13", "2018-02-14", "2018-02-15", "2018-02-16", 
                                                                                                   "2018-02-20", "2018-02-21", "2018-02-22", "2018-02-23", "2018-02-26", 
                                                                                                   "2018-02-27", "2018-02-28", "2018-03-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-03-05", 
                                                                                                   "2018-03-06", "2018-03-07", "2018-03-08", "2018-03-09", "2018-03-12", 
                                                                                                   "2018-03-13", "2018-03-14", "2018-03-15", "2018-03-16", "2018-03-19", 
                                                                                                   "2018-03-20", "2018-03-21", "2018-03-22", "2018-03-23", "2018-03-26", 
                                                                                                   "2018-03-27", "2018-03-28", "2018-03-29", "2018-04-02", "2018-04-03", 
                                                                                                   "2018-04-04", "2018-04-05", "2018-04-06", "2018-04-09", "2018-04-10", 
                                                                                                   "2018-04-11", "2018-04-12", "2018-04-13", "2018-04-16", "2018-04-17", 
                                                                                                   "2018-04-18", "2018-04-19", "2018-04-20", "2018-04-23", "2018-04-24", 
                                                                                                   "2018-04-25", "2018-04-26", "2018-04-27", "2018-04-30", "2018-05-01", 
                                                                                                   "2018-05-02", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-04", "2018-05-07", "2018-05-08", 
                                                                                                   "2018-05-09", "2018-05-10", "2018-05-11", "2018-05-14", "2018-05-15", 
                                                                                                   "2018-05-16", "2018-05-17", "2018-05-18", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-22", 
                                                                                                   "2018-05-23", "2018-05-24", "2018-05-25", "2018-05-29", "2018-05-30", 
                                                                                                   "2018-05-31", "2018-06-01", "2018-06-04", "2018-06-05", "2018-06-06", 
                                                                                                   "2018-06-07", "2018-06-08", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-12", "2018-06-13", 
                                                                                                   "2018-06-14", "2018-06-15", "2018-06-18", "2018-06-19", "2018-06-20", 
                                                                                                   "2018-06-21", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", 
                                                                                                   "2018-06-28", "2018-06-29", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-03", "2018-07-05", 
                                                                                                   "2018-07-06", "2018-07-09", "2018-07-10", "2018-07-11", "2018-07-12", 
                                                                                                   "2018-07-13", "2018-07-16", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-18", "2018-07-19", 
                                                                                                   "2018-07-20", "2018-07-23", "2018-07-24", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-26", 
                                                                                                   "2018-07-27", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-02", 
                                                                                                   "2018-08-03", "2018-08-06", "2018-08-07", "2018-08-08", "2018-08-09", 
                                                                                                   "2018-08-10", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-16", 
                                                                                                   "2018-08-17", "2018-08-20", "2018-08-21", "2018-08-22", "2018-08-23", 
                                                                                                   "2018-08-24", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-28", "2018-08-29", "2018-08-30", 
                                                                                                   "2018-08-31", "2018-09-04", "2018-09-05", "2018-09-06", "2018-09-07", 
                                                                                                   "2018-09-10", "2018-09-11", "2018-09-12", "2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", 
                                                                                                   "2018-09-17", "2018-09-18", "2018-09-19", "2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", 
                                                                                                   "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", "2018-09-27", "2018-09-28", 
                                                                                                   "2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "2018-10-05", 
                                                                                                   "2018-10-08", "2018-10-09", "2018-10-10", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-12", 
                                                                                                   "2018-10-15", "2018-10-16", "2018-10-17"), c("Open", "High", 
                                                                                                                                                "Low", "Close")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something related to your data. The following code works fine:

```
library(quantmod)
tmp <- getSymbols('IBM', from=Sys.Date()-20, auto.assign=FALSE)
tmp <- tmp[,1:4]  # OHLC data only
d <- dygraph(tmp) %>% 
  dyCandlestick() %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20) %>% 
  dyAnnotation(x=as.character(Sys.Date()-10), text='aha')
d
```